# Datatables row reorder event issue

Tags: javascript, datatable

```
var table =$("#exampleList").DataTable({
    paging:false,
    rowReorder:false
}

});

table.on('row-reorder',function(e, diff,edit){
    for(var i=0, ien = diff.length ; i<ien ; i++){
        var rowData = table.row(diff[i].node).data();
        sequence  = sequence + "_" + rowData[0];
    }

var data = table.rows().data();

data.each(function (value, index) {
    alert('Data in index: ' + index + ' is: ' + value);
});

});
```

Hi,
I am new to datatables. Issue I am having right now is I cant get the latest value in my table after the user reorder the row. The code above only shows the value before the reorder occurs. I need to get the latest reorder sequence so I can update the database.

Comment: you want to update sequence number in DB?

Comment: @user2352577L : Yes, I am passing a HTTP request with the sequence appended behind the url . Eg. eqwe.com/index?seq=(the sequence of the table)

Comment: i still don't get your meaning.

Answer (score 2):

What you need to do is wait a few milliseconds before trying to read the data.

```
table.on('row-reorder',function(e, diff, edit){
    for(var i=0, ien = diff.length ; i<ien ; i++){
        var rowData = table.row(diff[i].node).data();
        sequence  = sequence + "_" + rowData[0];
    }

    setTimeout(()=> { lookAtData() }, 10);

});

function lookAtData() {
    var data = table.rows().data();

    data.each(function (value, index) {
        alert('Data in index: ' + index + ' is: ' + value);
    });
}
```

Comment: It works this way, but I don't understand why.

Answer (score -2):

You should use `column-reorder` not `row-reorder`.

Please try :

```
var rdata = table .columns().order().data();
console.log(rdata);
```

It will get the data after columns ordering.

Comment: you should use `column-reorder` not `row-reorder`